# Where in the C++ Standard does it say that sizeof(wchar_t) <= sizeof(long) and sizeof(bool) <= sizeof(long)?

Tags: c++, c++11, sizeof

Mr. Stroustrup wrote the following on page 149 of his new book (TCPL 4th edition)

```
1 <= sizeof(wchar_t) <= sizeof(long)
```

I couldn't find anything in the Standard supporting the last inequality above. I could say the same for `sizeof(bool) <= sizeof(long)`.

**Edit**: In `3.9.1p5`  you'll find:

> Type wchar_t shall have the same size, signedness, and alignment requirements (3.11) as one of the other integral types, called its underlying type.

which gives support to the inequality

```
sizeof(wchar_t) <= sizeof(long long)
```

but not to

```
sizeof(wchar_t) <= sizeof(long)
```

But I couldn't find anything confirming

```
sizeof(bool) <= sizeof(long)
```

Comment: `sizeof(bool) <= sizeof(long)` is probably guaranteed by [conv.rank]/1: "The rank of `bool` shall be less than the rank of all other standard integer types." (Although "rank" doesn't strictly imply "size".)

Comment: An extended integer type is also an integral type; so if your implementation had a `int128_t`, I think 3.9.1/5 also allowed `wchar_t` to be bigger than a 64-bit `long long`.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to imagine a  `sizeof(wchar_t)>N && sizeof(long)<=N` implementation for any value of N, let alone one on which anyone would consider using `wchar_t`.  That said:

In fact, I think it's wrong.  4.5 "Integral promotions" p2 explicitly allows for the possibility:

> `2.` A prvalue of type char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t (3.9.1) can be converted to a prvalue of the first of
>   the following types that can represent all the values of its underlying type: int, unsigned int, long int,
>   unsigned long int, long long int, or unsigned long long int. ***If none of the types in that list can
>   represent all the values of its underlying type***, a prvalue of type char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t can be
>   converted to a prvalue of its underlying type.

and 5.3.3 "sizeof" p1 explicitly leaves the actual sizes implementation-defined:

> `1.` [...] The result of sizeof applied to any other fundamental type (3.9.1) is
>   implementation-defined. [ ***Note: in particular, sizeof(bool), sizeof(char16_t), sizeof(char32_t), and
>   sizeof(wchar_t) are implementation-defined.***
>    76 — end note ] [ Note: See 1.7 for the definition of byte
>   and 3.9 for the definition of object representation. — end note ]

While 5.3.3 is enough to leave the relative sizes open to question, the normative possibility of `wchar_t` being unrepresentable in any standard type I think makes it unquestionable.